# Codeginiter : chmod(): Invalid argument error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, pdftk

I am using `pdftk` library for modify the pdf files. but i am getting the  `chmod(): Invalid argument` error.

**Following is my code :**

```
  include('fillpdf/createXFDF.php');
    $fdf_file = 'fillpdf/acord.fdf';
    $acord = array();
    $acord['******'] = 'a';
    $acord['******'] = 'a';
    $pdf_file_url  = 'http://localhost/******/fillpdf/Cancellation.pdf';
    $fdf = createXFDF( $pdf_file_url, $acord );
    // print_r($fdf); die;
           if ($fp = fopen($fdf_file, 'w')) { 
                chmod($fdf, 777);
                fwrite($fp, $fdf, strlen($fdf));
                $CREATED = TRUE;
            } else {
                echo 'Unable to create file: ' . $fdf_file . '<br><br>';
                $CREATED = FALSE;
            } 
            // var_dump($CREATED); die;
    fclose($fp);
    $command = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PDFtk\\bin\\pdftk.exe" C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\*******\\fillpdf\\Cancellation.pdf fill_form acord.fdf output C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\*******\\fillpdf\\Cancellation_new.pdf';
    exec($command);
```

I have given all the necessary permission to folder and files. but don't know what is wrong??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to give `chmod($fdf,0777);` to `$fdf`. It's not even the file. as per your code the `$fdf = createXFDF( $pdf_file_url, $acord );` is calling function and it's not file. so just comment the `chmod($fdf,0777);` line and check your code is working or not??

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hmmm!! i think that's right... the first parameter should be `filename`. thanks for  the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...For `chmod()` function first number is always zero.

```
chmod(file,mode);
```

The mode parameter consists of four numbers:

1.The first number is always zero

2.The second number specifies permissions for the owner

3.The third number specifies permissions for the owner's user group

4.The fourth number specifies permissions for everybody else

```
include('fillpdf/createXFDF.php');
    $fdf_file = 'fillpdf/acord.fdf';
    $acord = array();
    $acord['******'] = 'a';
    $acord['******'] = 'a';
    $pdf_file_url  = 'http://localhost/******/fillpdf/Cancellation.pdf';
    $fdf = createXFDF( $pdf_file_url, $acord );
    // print_r($fdf); die;
           if ($fp = fopen($fdf_file, 'w')) { 
                chmod($fdf,0777);
                fwrite($fp, $fdf, strlen($fdf));
                $CREATED = TRUE;
            } else {
                echo 'Unable to create file: ' . $fdf_file . '<br><br>';
                $CREATED = FALSE;
            } 
            // var_dump($CREATED); die;
    fclose($fp);
    $command = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PDFtk\\bin\\pdftk.exe" C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\*******\\fillpdf\\Cancellation.pdf fill_form acord.fdf output C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\*******\\fillpdf\\Cancellation_new.pdf';
    exec($command);
```

Comment: i tried that too... `chmod($fdf,0777);`  but not worked :(

Comment: see here for more http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_chmod.asp

Comment: try using `0777` to `0755`

Comment: echo `$fdf` ..does it is right file folder name with right name?

Comment: Yes that's right because my `createXFDF` function is calling. i did check it